# Convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ and $\sum \frac{a_n}{4^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

An arbitrary series, $\sum a_n$, will converge to 3 given the following condition: $lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| \to 3$. Does $\sum \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ and $\sum \frac{a_n}{4^n}$ converge? First, I would like to say that this looks a lot like the ratio test! According to the ratio test, if the limit is greater than 1, then the series diverges. So there's that. Not much information about it there. We can, however, look at what it is approaching. It is approaching 3. That means the ratio between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n}$ shouldn't be very big. We also know that $2^n$ and $4^n$ grow very fast, in fact, they are one of the fastest growing functions, just behind the factorials and $n^n$ functions. So they should be able to converge given that the series $a_n$ grows slower than the exponential functions...but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: You can very easily solve this. Just apply the ratio test to those series' sequences and there you have it.

Comment: this is a n00b question, but how would I do that exactly? Do I do $|\frac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{a_n}{2^n}}|$ or something similar?

Comment: @MetaphysicsofMorals yes that's exactly right. If you need help convincing yourself of that, consider the series $\sum b_n$, where $b_n=\frac{a_n}{2^n}$. We want to know if $\sum b_n$ converges. So, do the ratio test on that series and you get $\Big|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\Big|$ is equal to what you proposed.

Comment: Let 

$$b_n=\frac{a_n}{2^n},$$

then 

\begin{align}
L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\frac{2^n}{a_n}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|.
\end{align}

Since you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\to 3$, you can directly apply the [Ratio Test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/RatioTest.aspx). You can do the same for $$c_n = \frac{a_n}{4^n}.$$